# Refresh Collaspible List within dynamically created Collapsible-set

Tags: jquery-mobile

Example Code on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MqDFt/6/

Background on this, it is a dialog window that appears, and upon the user starting to enter a search query, it displays a number of results found. Here is an example of the results that would be returned via AJAX from PHP:

```
<div data-role='collapsible' data-mini='true'>
    <h3>appcent.com<span style='float: right;margin-top: -16px;padding-right: 10px;'>(1)</span></h3>
    <ul data-role='listview'>
        <li><a href='adv_dns_displayResults.php?lid=87e2a2ef68c71c220d6a519ab6d668b2'><span style='float: left;'>appcent.com</span><span style='float: right;'>2012-01-30 19:02:46</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role='collapsible' data-mini='true'>
    <h3>apallen.net<span style='float: right;margin-top: -16px;padding-right: 10px;'>(2)</span></h3>
    <ul data-role='listview'>
        <li><a href='adv_dns_displayResults.php?lid=8df9e81f2245f9cae41f1e95899598b3'><span style='float: left;'>apallen.net</span><span style='float: right;'>2010-07-30 15:37:32</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='adv_dns_displayResults.php?lid=a9387b995e88c7573141451546839e96'><span style='float: left;'>apallen.net</span><span style='float: right;'>2010-07-30 15:37:32</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role='collapsible' data-mini='true'>
    <h3>aptfire.com<span style='float: right;margin-top: -16px;padding-right: 10px;'>(2)</span></h3>
    <ul data-role='listview'>
        <li><a href='adv_dns_displayResults.php?lid=7de36861bcc8a2064ce7f428cc384c8c'><span style='float: left;'>aptfire.com</span><span style='float: right;'>2011-10-13 10:29:16</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='adv_dns_displayResults.php?lid=bf8c93976d5bba46b7313b9bb990ef3c'><span style='float: left;'>aptfire.com</span><span style='float: right;'>2011-10-13 10:29:18</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The Collapsible-Set refreshes properly, yet listview does not. I have tried to refresh the list view, trigger create, and a combination of other things.

Comment: Have you tried to check on the php page that you are sending this to, if it displays the variable `$_GET['q']`. Did you try echoing the `q` variable in the `<form method="get" action="php/adv_dns_pastLookup.php">`? Reason for this is you need to check if the php page can be able to receive the parameter.

Comment: Yes, and a valid concern. `$_GET['q']` is passed and results are returned when AJAX runs. The text shown above is the Response I get if I pass `q` = 'ap' and `items_per_page` = '10'.

Comment: @FranzNoel If you want to see it in the wild: [link](http://www.yrmailfrom.me/tools/dns/adv_dns.php) Use the **Past Search** button and then enter a query. The results will create collapsed boxes that contain lists of the results. It's those lists I am now trying to refresh properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct code:

```
$("#pastSearchResults ul").each(function(i) {
    $(this).listview(); 
});
```

Notes:

1. Use simplified selector which returns all "ul" tags under div
   "#pastSearchResults"
2. The selector return a list, not just one item so iterate over it
3. Call listview() without param "refresh" since this is the first the list is created (not old and refreshed)

Comment: Thanks. Tested and works as needed. I kept trying to just run a refresh, thinking it would do it for all sub-lists. The `.each()` works great.